# Remove row from CSV that contains empty cell using Python

Tags: python, csv

I am splitting a CSV file based on a column with dates into separate files. However, some rows do contain a date but the others cells are empty. I want to remove these rows that contain empty cells from the CSV. But I'm not sure how to do this.

Here's is my code:

```
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)

with open(main_file, "r") as fp:
    root = csv.reader(fp, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
    result = collections.defaultdict(list)
    next(root)
    for row in root:
        year = row[0].split("-")[0]
        result[year].append(row)

for i,j in result.items():
    row_count = sum(1 for row in j)
        print(row_count)
        file_path = "%s%s-%s.csv"%(src_path, i, row_count)
        with open(file_path, 'w') as fp:
            writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
            writer.writerows(j)
```

Comment: I know of its existence, I've never used it and maybe it's a good time to start  ;)

Comment: Why not a simple test before `result[year].append(row)` that checks there is data in the other fields, e.g. `if row[1]: result[year].append(row)`?

Comment: This does not work because result is already a dictionary. Error msg:IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pandas is perfect for this, especially if you want this to be easily adjusted to, say, other file formats. Of course one could consider it an overkill.
To just remove rows with empty cells:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.read_csv('example.csv', sep='\t')
>>> print data
   A   B   C
0   1   2  5
1 NaN   1  9
2   3   4  4
>>> data.dropna()
   A   B   C
0   1   2  5
2   3   4  4
>>> data.dropna().to_csv('example_clean.csv')
```

I leave performing the splitting and saving into separate files using pandas as an exercise to start learning this great package if you want :)

Answer (score 0):

This would skip all all rows with at least one empty cell:

```
with open(main_file, "r") as fp:
    ....
    for row in root:
         if not all(map(len, row)):
              continue
```

Comment: Can you show some example csv content with empty cells.

Comment: This file is not `\t` separated. In fact, its doesn't seem to be  `csv` file at all.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is Best in Python for handling any type of data processing.For help you can go through on link :- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html